# Updating an array of objects properties based on another object

Tags: javascript

I want to update an arrays of objects (league table) based on another array of object (match result) by finding id from the two teams and update the stats on the league table,

Just like how **football(soccer)** league table works.

This is how the league standing looks

```
let leagueStandings = [
  {id:'49e93e0d', played: 0, scored: 0, conceded: 0, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 0},
  {id:'24e5ddb8', played: 0, scored: 0, conceded: 0, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 0}
]
```

I get this match result array of objects for both teams, which I need to update on the league standings..

```
let matchResult = [
  { id: '49e93e0d', scored: 2, conceded: 1, win: true, draw: false },
  { id: '24e5ddb8', scored: 1, conceded: 2, win: false, draw: false }
]
```

So I came up with this code

```
function updateStandings(match) {
    let team;
    match.forEach(prop => { //loop both teams in result and update their respective stats
        team = leagueStandings.find(team => team.id === prop.id); // find the team to update by id
        team.played++
        team.scored += prop.scored
        team.conceded += prop.conceded
        team.goalDifference += (prop.scored - prop.conceded)
        if (prop.win) team.won++
        if (prop.draw) team.drawn++
        if (!prop.win && !prop.draw) team.lost++
    });
}

updateStandings(matchResult)

// outputs the expected the result
[
  { id: '49e93e0d', played: 1, scored: 2, conceded: 1, won: 1, drawn: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: '24e5ddb8', played: 1, scored: 1, conceded: 2, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 1 }
]
```

Which actually works and does the job, however I think there is better way to do it? also the league standings array will contain large nums of teams, so I'm not sure if it's the best way?

expected output

```
[
  { id: '49e93e0d', played: 1, scored: 2, conceded: 1, won: 1, drawn: 0, lost: 0 },
  { id: '24e5ddb8', played: 1, scored: 1, conceded: 2, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 1 }
]
```

Full code [**HERE**](https://playcode.io/813021/)

Comment: It's not likely that there is a way to do this with significant time savings. Consider [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `find()` function in your solution will go through every `leagueStandings` item to match the `id`

Because `leagueStandings` is unordered on average it has to loop though half the items before it finds a match.

This can be fixed by indexing by ID

consider using this structure for `leagueStandings`:

```
let leagueStandings = {
  '49e93e0d': {played: 0, scored: 0, conceded: 0, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 0},
  '24e5ddb8': {played: 0, scored: 0, conceded: 0, won: 0, drawn: 0, lost: 0}
}
```

Now you can change this line:

`team = leagueStandings.find(team => team.id === prop.id);`

to this:

`team = leagueStandings[prop.id];`

and do an indexed lookup